# Difference in loading times with and without namespace

Tags: c++, cout

I'm fairly new to C++ so I hope this question isn't dumb, plus I've searched around and couldn't find an answer.

So this brings my to my question, is there any difference in loading times between calling **std::cout** and calling **cout** when using namespace std is added to the code? I imagine that if there is a difference it should be unnoticeable, but I'd like to be sure before turning in my project.

By the way, in my university we are told that **using namespace std** is okay (I've already read at lengths on that and whether it is good practice or not is not in question right now).

Comment: I feel a less flippant answer than David gave can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: _"By the way, in my university we are told that using namespace std"_ - You should transfer to another school.

Comment: You should use `using namespace` with caution, prefer listing each symbol, such as `using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. And performance should be the last of your concerns when making these kinds of "micro" code decisions.

Comment: It's not about performance of the program but more curiosity, I didn't express myself as well as I should have. Thanks!